# iMac "pauses" every minute or so

Tags: imac, performance

I have an older (2010) iMac that has been running smoothly until a few weeks ago. Since then, the computer has started to "pause" in increasing frequency.

During the "pauses", the computer stops whatever it is doing – streaming a movie (the movie freezes), updating text that I type (the text cursor freezes), switching to a different tab or menu in an app (the view doesn't switch) – and seems stuck for about half a minute, then it continues and works normally for another few minutes. While the computer pauses, I can still move the mouse pointer nomally and even switch to another app by clicking on its window. Switching to another app by keyboard shortcut doesn't work. Sometimes I can, and sometimes I cannot use this other app normally for a brief period before it "pauses" also. Usually all open apps are stuck in this way at the same time. Sometimes, the spinning beachball appears.

I have already erased the hard drive and reinstalled the system (the most recent version this iMac is compatible with is 10.13), but the problem persists, so it must be hardware related or system software related. The mouse is connected by a USB cable, the keyboard by Bluetooth, which might have something to do with the mouse working during the "pause".

The "pauses" have increased in frequency. At first, a few weeks ago, it was just a streaming movie "hanging" every couple of minutes, and I thought it was due to a network problem (e.g. the streaming server being overloaded), but two days ago the "pause" began to happen every minute or so, and the frequency hasn't dropped since then.

Anyone know what the problem might be and what I might try to do?

Comment: does the fan spin up? sounds like some sort of serious thermal throttle, especially a Mac of that age, try giving the fans a clean and replace thermal paste if you know how to

Comment: I would point to a failing drive as the culprit. The two 2010 models of iMac came standard with a spinning disk (21" iMac with 500GB, 1 or 2 TB; 27" iMac with 1 or 2TB and/or 256GB SSD.) At 12 years of age, this iMac is a bit long in the tooth (for healthy spinning disks, that is.) You should make a backup right away (if you don't already) and consider replacing the internal HD(s) ASAP!

Comment: @NathanEllis No, the fans don't spin up. The computer doesn't feel warmer to the touch than usually, either.

Comment: @IconDaemon I found a related question that seems to confirm your hunch: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17160/imac-freezing-intermittently-every-few-minutes-how-can-i-fix-this Luckily I have been backing up everything continually, so at least my data is safe.

Comment: It sounds like Bluetooth may be implicated in the failure chain. Do you have a USB keyboard that you can try using and turn Bluetooth off completely?

Comment: @pion Yeah, thank you, I thought of this. The problem seems to at least get better, when I turn Bluetooth off. I don't have a USB keyboard, so I couldn't properly test this. I just watched half an hour of a movie with Bluetooth off, and the problem seemed to have disappeared, but when I turned it on again, the problem didn't reappear until this morning, so I'm not sure. I need to find a USB keyboard and test this for a few days to be sure.